Is averaging over initial polarization equivalent to subensemble averaging over spin states in QFT?
I've been thinking about the concept of ensemble averages and whether polarization averaging falls under this category. For this post, we will ignore the discussions relevent for polarization sum. I am more concerned about initial spin average or initial polarization average. I understand why we need to do spin sum for final states but here, I wish to know, if we can interpret the initial polarization averaging as subensemble average of spin sum where rest of the degrees of freedom are fixed and only the spin degree of freedom is left free. The reason why I think it could work is following:

Ensemble Average: If I  can think of an ensemble average as evolving a system from all possible initial conditions (consistent with macroscopic constraints) and each of the microstates as an interation with different initial condition. Then, the ensemble average over all microstate gives me a statistical description of the system's behavior when I become ignorant of the specific initial condition.

Polarization Averaging: In quantum field theory, we calculate the cross section for each possible initial spin state of the system. Then, we average over all these spin states, assuming we're ignorant about the specific spin state of the particle.


Now, here’s where I get confused:

Polarization averaging seems conceptually similar to an ensemble average, but it feels like a restricted or smaller case since we're only averaging over spin states, not the entire phase space.
Would it be correct to say that polarization averaging represents a subensemble average, focusing only on a subset of degrees of freedom (like spin)?
How does this distinction hold up in statistical mechanics? Does this limited averaging process fit into the broader framework of ensembles, or is it something separate altogether?

Any insights would be appreciated!
